# Forwarding windows credentials from web application to web service

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication, credentials

Hello fellow programmers ! I need your help with an issue that i can't seem to resolve. I have a REST web service that is hosted on a virtual machine (VM 2) using IIS and when poked directly everything works fine. I get all the data needed and everyone is happy. **Note that this web service requires windows credentials to operate.**

Now this web service is to be consumed by a larger web application hosted on another virtual machine (VM 1) using IIS too. Here comes the problem, when using this web application, whenever i want to access the page that pokes the web service in the backend i get an instant error 401 : *Could not get the user profile (Unauthorized Unauthorized)*

Schema of the situation :

[image]

I googled alot and tried many different things. I tried to impersonate the call without success.

Here is how the web application's request is built :

```
public UserProfile GetProfile()
    {
        var wi = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        var wic = wi.Impersonate();

        try
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("profile")
                              {
                                  Method = Method.GET,
                                  JsonSerializer = RestJsonSerializer.Default,
                                  UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                              };

            var response = this.client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    $"Could not get the user profile ({response.StatusCode} {response.StatusDescription})");
            }

            return RestJsonSerializer.Default.Deserialize<UserProfile>(response);
        }
        finally
        {
            wic.Undo();
        }
    }
```

IIS settings for web service AND web application are :

- Anonymous Authentication = Disabled
- ASP.NET Impersonation = Enabled
- Forms Authentication = Disabled
- Windows Authentication = Enabled

Any help or tip is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do both VMs share the same AD domain?

Comment: Yes they share the same domain

Comment: Search for Kerberos delegation and double-hop.